# Addition, multiplication, substitution queries

Tags: arrays, algorithm, segment-tree

Given a one dimensional integer array A of length N. We need Q queries each of one of following types:

**NOTE : M is fixed to be 10^9 + 7**

**Query 1 : 1 x y v :** It means adding v to all element from x to y in 1 base indexed array and then take them modulo M.

```
for (i = x; i <= y; i++)    
    A[i] += v;
    A[i] %= M;
```

**Query 2 : 2 x y v** : It means multiplying v to all element from x to y in 1 base indexed array and then take them modulo M.

```
for (i = x; i <= y; i++)    
    A[i] *= v
    A[i] %= M
```

**Query 3 : 3 x y v :** It means substituting v to all element from x to y in 1 base indexed array.

```
for (i = x; i <= y; i++)    
    A[i] = v
```

**Query 4 : 4 x y :** This is a report query which needs to find the sum of the values in A from x to y, i.e.,

```
sum = 0;
for (i = x; i <= y; i++)
    sum += A[i]
    sum %= M
Output sum.
```

Now how to handle these queries ? I know to handle queries if it were addition and sum queries with segment tree. But have no idea for this one. Please help me to solve this problem.

Constraints :  1 ≤ N,Q ≤ 10^5 and 1 ≤ Initial value of A[i],v ≤ 10^9

Comment: what do you mean "how to handle?" You have good pseudocode in the question already. What are you actually asking here?

Comment: in the Query 4:  "sum %= M"  you sure you want this... you mod your sum and then add to it... ?

Comment: @jdl Yeah.. I need to do this way

Comment: @chiliNUT I cant do this way reason being the count of such queries is very large.

Comment: @chiliNUT Please read problem carefully. Its taking MOD at each step. So there is no need of such library

Comment: Your arrays of 10,000 don't seem that large. What's the problem with what you wrote? Implement it in c, and see if there's a problem at all. The stuff also seems pleasingly parallel, BTW.

Comment: @AmiTavory Suppose we have 10^5 elements and 10^5 queries then each query is in worst will be running in O(N) that is 10^5. so total complexity becomes 10^5 * 10^5 that is not affordable

Comment: No time to write an answer now, but you can use segment trees/lazy propagation/linear polynomials over (**Z**/M)[x] under composition.

Comment: (If you edit the question for another reason, please correct the title.) See also [Using lazy propagation for Add to & Initialize a range, Multiply scalar or report running sum](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31224883/3789665).

Comment: @FalconUA I know Fenwick Tree . But how this can be solved by them ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: @greybeard I know Lazy Propogation. But how it will help here ?