# Using lazy propagation for queries of more than 2 types

Tags: c, algorithm, segment-tree, lazy-propagation

I have a question with a lot of queries which are of four types:

1. Add to range.
2. Initialize a range.
3. Multiply a range with scalar.
4. Find running sum over a range.

Since queries are in huge numbers I have to use segment tree with lazy propagation but I am stuck on how to use lazy propagation on more than 2 types of queries. 
How would I be able to identify that when updates are to be made later, then what type of update(i.e. addition, multiplication, initializing) is to be made?

Comment: I think you need to explain more about what you're doing (though I recognize that [Nafeeur Rahman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2130104/nafeeur-rahman) seems to understand what you're after — but I'm not sure I follow his answer, either).  How big are your 'huge numbers' — 10s, 100s, 1000s, more?  How are the queries formatted?  What data is the running sum summed over?  Are the values integers or floating point (or something else)?

Comment: Revisiting this question, I'm still not certain what a `range` is: [lower, upper) or the set of integers between two bounds?

Comment: @greybeard range is the elements of array within two bounds where bounds are defined by lower and upper index.

Comment: There is an array involved? You don't say so. Not in the question proper up to now, that is.

Comment: **Moderator notice**: Questions about on-going contests are not off-topic for Stack Overflow. Moderators can and will not police third-party agreements and that includes contest rules. It is up to the contest to discipline or police their rules. Please do not flag this post just because it is about a CodeChef contest.

Answer (score 0):

1.2.3. This is the simple initialization and update part.

```
struct info
{
    int prop,sum;
} tree[mx*3];

void update(int node,int b,int e,int i,int j,int x)
{
    if (i > e || j < b) return;
    if (b >= i && e <= j)
    {
        tree[node].sum+=((e-b+1)*x);
        tree[node].prop+=x;
        return;
    }
    int Left=node*2;
    int Right=(node*2)+1;
    int mid=(b+e)/2;
    update(Left,b,mid,i,j,x);
    update(Right,mid+1,e,i,j,x);
    tree[node].sum=tree[Left].sum+tree[Right].sum+(e-b+1)*tree[node].prop;

}
```

4.This is the query part:

```
int query(int node,int b,int e,int i,int j,int carry=0)
{
    if (i > e || j < b) return 0;

    if(b>=i and e<=j) return tree[node].sum+carry*(e-b+1);

    int Left=node<<1;
    int Right=(node<<1)+1;
    int mid=(b+e)>>1;

    int p1 = query(Left, b,mid, i, j, carry+tree[node].prop); 
    int p2 = query(Right, mid+1, e, i, j,carry+tree[node].prop);

    return p1+p2;
}
```

And from `main`

```
update(1,1,number_of_element,first_range,last_range,value);
query(1,1,n,first_range,last_range);
```

> Here, tree is the segment tree. Every node will contain two
>   informations. One is with which number you added before. prop will
>   store that history. And sum is the total value of that node.

**After your comment:

```
//Initialization:

void init(int node,int b,int e)
{
    if(b==e)
    {
        tree[node]=arr[b];
        return;
    }
    int Left=node*2;
    int Right=node*2+1;
    int mid=(b+e)/2;
    init(Left,b,mid);
    init(Right,mid+1,e);
    tree[node]=tree[Left]+tree[Right];
}
```

Comment: How to do update for multiply and initialization at the same time. I can do it with 2 at a time but for all 4 together I am not getting correct results.

Comment: You can initialize by the update function. Then you have to change one matter just. first_range and last_range will be same.

Comment: No, that's not necessary. Same update function you can use.

Comment: prop here works for add. Now when I need to go for multiplication order matters then how to handle it using the same function.

Comment: You can add different prop for sum and multiplication. Like prop_add and prop_mul. I think.

Comment: Can you to tell how to add and initialize using the same function?

Comment: Have learned it very recently and the only problem I have solved is where I have to add and find running sum.Now I am having problem to handle prop for more then 2 type of queries..

Comment: Then I will suggest you to try these problem first. I think these problems will be easy for you.  http://lightoj.com/volume_problemcategory.php?user_id=8333&category=Segment%20Tree/Interval%20Tree

Comment: I have added initialization part also. This part also can be done by update function. Now try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly give the Update funtcion another argument, call it Query. Depending on the value of that argument, the corresponding operation is done.

For additions and multiplications, the information for the lazy propagation can be contained in two fields:

Let A be the initial value of the leaf and there is an arbitrary series of multiplications and additions, for example: +u +v *w +x *y +z.
Apply those operations on lazy1. So its value would be: ((u+v) * w +x) * y + z.  lazy2 should only contain the multiplications, this would be w * y.

To update the node, first multiply by lazy2, then add lazy1.

Reason:
Apply the operations to the initial value A and you get: A * w * y + ((u+v)*w +x)*y + z. It is trivial that only the multiplications affect the initial value A directly. So those can be stored in one field and the other field could contain the additions and also the multiplications have to be applied on it as the order is important here.

Comment: What to do in case of initialization?

Comment: Take a third field for that and by the same time reset lazy1 and lazy2 as we don't need to perform the operations stored in there any more. So you would in case of update or query first check if lazy3 is set for that node and set the sum to (R-L+1)*lazy3